# Mate panel opens application instead of caja

Tags: debian, gnome, mate

I run Mate 1.4.2

When I click 'Home Folder' from 'Places' menu on top it launches `easytag` application instead of `caja`. I.e. completely unrelated application.
I have no idea how it happened and have no clue where to look to fix it.

When I browse folders within `caja` it works fine.

Please, suggest where to look first.

Comment: Deleted my answer, since it did not address your problem. What happens when you double click a folder icon in the desktop? It opens correctly with `caja`? Is `caja` set as the default file manager? What happens if you just run `caja` from a terminal?

Comment: It opens fine when I double click on a desktop folder.
`caja` also runs from terminal as expected.
How do I check that caja is default manager? I think that is the area we're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I found the problem.

Go to System -> Preferred Applications.
On System tab the File Manager was set to EasyTag.

Have no idea how this come, but when I changed it back to "Open Folder" it obviously worked.

I guess it is a problem with Easytag debian package.
It adds itself as a file manager for some reason.
And because Easytag is alphabetically upper than "Open Folder" (`caja`) it was selected by default.

I am on Debian Wheezy.
If someone can confirm this behaviour after installing EasyTag I could file a bug for it.

Comment: If this answered your question and solved the error, please mark it as excepted. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, been driving me batty opening VLC for a year whenever I clicked on Places or the Trash can.  On a recent Mate with advanced menu I found it under the menu >> Preferences (aka Control Panel) >> Preferred Applications.